# How can I use pyspark.sql.function.lag to shift a column by a whole week instead of only one row?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

sales_shift-wrong is the output of my current code, sales_shift right is the desired output:

[Data and examples of current (incorrect) output and desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAqJB.png)

DATA:

| date | year | month | week | item | department | store | state | sales | sales_shifted | correct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | 2020 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1592 | TX | $ 149,674.59 | Null | Null |
| 02/01/2020 | 2020 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1592 | TX | $ 101,260.73 | $ 149,674.59 | Null |
| 03/01/2020 | 2020 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1592 | TX | $ 119,931.46 | $ 101,260.73 | Null |
| 04/01/2020 | 2020 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1592 | TX | $ 209,863.86 | $ 119,931.46 | Null |
| 05/01/2020 | 2020 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1592 | TX | $ 426,471.36 | $ 209,863.86 | Null |
| 06/01/2020 | 2020 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1592 | TX | $ 377,860.85 | $ 426,471.36 | $ 149,674.59 |
| 07/01/2020 | 2020 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1592 | TX | $ 127,632.41 | $ 377,860.85 | $ 101,260.73 |
| 08/01/2020 | 2020 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1592 | TX | $ 80,207.47 | $ 127,632.41 | $ 119,931.46 |
| 09/01/2020 | 2020 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1592 | TX | $ 62,149.50 | $ 80,207.47 | $ 209,863.86 |
| 10/01/2020 | 2020 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1592 | TX | $ 67,399.59 | $ 62,149.50 | $ 426,471.36 |
| 11/01/2020 | 2020 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1592 | TX | $ 90,867.58 | $ 67,399.59 | Null |
| 12/01/2020 | 2020 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1592 | TX | $ 113,211.99 | $ 90,867.58 | Null |
| 16/01/2020 | 2020 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1592 | TX | $ 67,096.92 | $ 113,211.99 | $ 377,860.85 |
| 17/01/2020 | 2020 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1592 | TX | $ 68,440.03 | $ 67,096.92 | $ 127,632.41 |
| 18/01/2020 | 2020 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1592 | TX | $ 91,116.59 | $ 68,440.03 | $ 80,207.47 |
| 19/01/2020 | 2020 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1592 | TX | $ 119,986.25 | $ 91,116.59 | $ 62,149.50 |
| 13/01/2020 | 2020 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1592 | TX | $ 72,911.67 | $ 119,986.25 | $ 67,399.59 |
| 14/01/2020 | 2020 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1592 | TX | $ 87,993.66 | $ 72,911.67 | $ 90,867.58 |
| 15/01/2020 | 2020 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1592 | TX | $ 69,015.89 | $ 87,993.66 | $ 113,211.99 |

I think the right approach to the desired solution (`sales_shift_right`) is by using a Window function, however, I haven't find the combination of parameters to obtain the results I want.

```
partitions = ['store', 'state_prov_cd', 'department', 'item', 'year', 'month', 'week']
date_col = ['week']

w = (
    Window
    .partitionBy(partitions)
    .orderBy(date_col)
  )

df_sales_shifted = (
    data
    .withColumn('sales_shifted', f.lag('sales', 1).over(w))
    .sort(partitions)
  )
```

Can someone suggest a better approach or spot the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one more column of `row_number` to facilitate partitioning:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

partitions = ['store', 'state', 'department', 'item', 'year', 'month', 'week']
partitions2 = ['store', 'state', 'department', 'item', 'rn']
date_col = ['week']

w = Window.partitionBy(partitions).orderBy(date_col)
w2 = Window.partitionBy(partitions2).orderBy(date_col)

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'rn',
    F.row_number().over(w)
).withColumn(
    'sales_shifted', 
    F.lag('sales').over(w2)
).drop('rn').orderBy('date')

df2.show()
+----------+----+-----+----+----+----------+-----+-----+------------+-------------+
|      date|year|month|week|item|department|store|state|       sales|sales_shifted|
+----------+----+-----+----+----+----------+-----+-----+------------+-------------+
|01/01/2020|2020|    1|   1|   1|         1| 1592|   TX|$ 149,674.59|         null|
|02/01/2020|2020|    1|   1|   1|         1| 1592|   TX|$ 101,260.73|         null|
|03/01/2020|2020|    1|   1|   1|         1| 1592|   TX|$ 119,931.46|         null|
|04/01/2020|2020|    1|   1|   1|         1| 1592|   TX|$ 209,863.86|         null|
|05/01/2020|2020|    1|   1|   1|         1| 1592|   TX|$ 426,471.36|         null|
|06/01/2020|2020|    1|   2|   1|         1| 1592|   TX|$ 377,860.85| $ 149,674.59|
|07/01/2020|2020|    1|   2|   1|         1| 1592|   TX|$ 127,632.41| $ 101,260.73|
|08/01/2020|2020|    1|   2|   1|         1| 1592|   TX| $ 80,207.47| $ 119,931.46|
|09/01/2020|2020|    1|   2|   1|         1| 1592|   TX| $ 62,149.50| $ 209,863.86|
|10/01/2020|2020|    1|   2|   1|         1| 1592|   TX| $ 67,399.59| $ 426,471.36|
|11/01/2020|2020|    1|   2|   1|         1| 1592|   TX| $ 90,867.58|         null|
|12/01/2020|2020|    1|   2|   1|         1| 1592|   TX|$ 113,211.99|         null|
|13/01/2020|2020|    1|   3|   1|         1| 1592|   TX| $ 72,911.67|  $ 67,399.59|
|14/01/2020|2020|    1|   3|   1|         1| 1592|   TX| $ 87,993.66|  $ 90,867.58|
|15/01/2020|2020|    1|   3|   1|         1| 1592|   TX| $ 69,015.89| $ 113,211.99|
|16/01/2020|2020|    1|   3|   1|         1| 1592|   TX| $ 67,096.92| $ 377,860.85|
|17/01/2020|2020|    1|   3|   1|         1| 1592|   TX| $ 68,440.03| $ 127,632.41|
|18/01/2020|2020|    1|   3|   1|         1| 1592|   TX| $ 91,116.59|  $ 80,207.47|
|19/01/2020|2020|    1|   3|   1|         1| 1592|   TX|$ 119,986.25|  $ 62,149.50|
+----------+----+-----+----+----+----------+-----+-----+------------+-------------+
```